# GeoServer transform POST request to GET?

Tags: geoserver, geoprocessing, web-service

I have the following geoprocessing POST request:

```
<wps:Execute xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:wps="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:wcs="http://www.opengis.net/wcs/1.1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.0.0" service="WPS" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0    http://schemas.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0/wpsAll.xsd">
<ows:Identifier>gs:BufferFeatureCollection</ows:Identifier>
 <wps:DataInputs>
   <wps:Input>
    <ows:Identifier>features</ows:Identifier>
    <wps:Reference mimeType="text/xml; subtype=wfs-collection/1.0" xlink:href="http://geoserver/wfs" method="POST">
    <wps:Body>
      <wfs:GetFeature xmlns:medford="http://medford.opengeo.org" service="WFS" version="1.0.0" outputFormat="GML2">
      <wfs:Query typeName="medford:firestations"/>
      </wfs:GetFeature>
    </wps:Body>
   </wps:Reference>
  </wps:Input>
  <wps:Input>
    <ows:Identifier>distance</ows:Identifier>
    <wps:Data>
     <wps:LiteralData>0.024</wps:LiteralData>
    </wps:Data>
  </wps:Input>
</wps:DataInputs>
<wps:ResponseForm>
  <wps:RawDataOutput mimeType="text/xml; subtype=wfs-collection/1.0">
  <ows:Identifier>result</ows:Identifier>
 </wps:RawDataOutput>
</wps:ResponseForm>
</wps:Execute>
```

How can I transform it to GET request?

Answer (score 1):

What are you actually trying to achieve here?  If you would like to make a this *WPS* (web processing service) request to the server, then you will need to use a POST action.  There is a fairly important difference between POST and GET actions (see [HTTP/1.1 Method Definitions](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html)) and although in some cases the handlers are incorrectly implemented on the server side according to these specifications, it's best to use the correct one.  In this case, you should be using a POST.

Unlike a GET request which you can easily create from within your request url, it's a little more tricky to create a POST request.

You could use *curl* to create the request, as shown at the botton of the page at http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/extensions/wps/processes.html, or use the [Request Builder](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/extensions/wps/requestbuilder.html#wps-request-builder) as recommended by Geoserver.  If you have any experience using Python, then I wrote a request script for a similar query on WFS POST requests (https://gist.github.com/guychisholm/3905362).  There are also a few browser plugins which allow you to manually fire up a HTTP Post Request.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for your replay! I m trying to execute a wps orchestration using http://www.taverna.org.uk/. The problem is that I have to use a REST Service using Get request method and to include all the wps parameters into the url... So, I have to tranform the above post request to get.

Comment: You can still use post requests for a REST service, although the WPS is not (yet) a RESTful service.  I'm not too familiar with taverna.org.uk.  What sort of control do you have over the client you are using to make the REST request.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

http://.../geoserver/wps?service=WPS&version=1.0.0&request=Execute&identifier=gs:Unique&DataInputs=attribute%3dnome;features%3d%40xlink%3ahref%3dhttp://.../geoserver/smurb/ows%3Fservice=WFS%26version=1.0.0%26request=GetFeature%26typeName=smurb:bairros_vigentes_3857

After xlink:href, is the hole "WFS subrequest".

If you want to return json, add `&RawDataOutput=result%3dformat%40mimetype%3dapplication%2Fjson` to the end.

This a sample of gs:Unique GET request.